# AWS RDS manual snapshot lifecycle

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, snapshot

Is there a way to set the lifecycle for a manual snapshot in AWS RDS? For the automated ones, there is a time that can be set, but I cannot find anything for the manual snapshots. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateSnapshot.html):

> Unlike automated backups, manual snapshots aren't subject to the backup retention period. **Snapshots don't expire**.

It means that you would have to develop your own, **custom solution** for that. For example using a lambda function which periodically is invoked and checks for old snapshots to remove them.

Comment: Thanks. I developed a custom script to delete old snapshots.